# How to group by one column if condition is true in another column summing values in third column with pandas

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I can't think of how to do this:
As the headline explains I want to group a dataframe by the column `acquired_month` only if another column contains `Closed Won`(in the example I made a helper column that just marks `True` if that condition is fulfilled although I'm not sure that step is necessary). Then if those conditions are met I want to sum the values of a third column but can't think how to do it. Here is my code so far:

`us_lead_scoring.loc[us_lead_scoring['Stage'].str.contains('Closed Won'), 'closed_won_binary'] = True acquired_date = us_lead_scoring.groupby('acquired_month')['closed_won_binary'].sum()`

but this just sums the true false column not the `sum` column if the true false column is true after the `acquired_month` groupby. Any direction appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: what column is necessary `sum`  Ca nyou add some small data sample to question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If need aggregate column `col` replace non matched values to `0` values in [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and then aggregate `sum`:

```
us_lead_scoring = pd.DataFrame({'Stage':['Closed Won1','Closed Won2','Closed', 'Won'],
                                'col':[1,3,5,6],
                                'acquired_month':[1,1,1,2]})

out = (us_lead_scoring['col'].where(us_lead_scoring['Stage']
                             .str.contains('Closed Won'), 0)
                             .groupby(us_lead_scoring['acquired_month'])
                             .sum()
                             .reset_index(name='SUM'))
     
print (out)
   acquired_month  SUM
0               1    4
1               2    0
```

Comment: Thanks for this! I ended up just doing it in a few steps by getting a dataframe of only `stage == closed won` then running the groupby and summing after that.